# about java , can website use the same thread to deal with all client request?

Tags: java, queue

I have a tomcat website. My clients upload lists of worker IDs for querying details(name, age, address etc.). My website don't have these data, and have to query them from another website(i call it UPPER SITE) which can just query one worker ID one time. My site job is just to make it AUTOMATICALLY. And the problem is UPPER SITE can be queried one per second.That means my site can run only one querying thead.I am confused. One client upload will arise one query thead.How to make them all use only one querying thead? Can Queue do this? or others? My website is a singeton website.

Comment: You can configure the thread pool for the server to be 1. That doesn't mean it's a good idea of course. ;)  Why do you want to do this as there is likely to be a better solution to the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Instead of limiting it to one, try allowing multiple threads, that is the better solution. If the upper site can only process one and you don't have control over it, then try something like a query queue, but limiting to one thread.. that is not a good idea.

Comment: One more approach can be to keep track of last requested time and let the new request wait until the wait (or queue it) time is over?
This is in reference to you stating that UPPER site allows only one req/sec.

Comment: @PeterLawrey can you share your better solution?

Comment: My point was; If you share with us the reason you believe you need to do this, we might be able to offer a better solution.

Comment: @PeterLawrey UPPER SITE belongs to our headquarters, about one query per second is their rules, I suppose it's about their performances.why they do not support batch?They did not tell us officially.We can not change it.

Comment: If you have a requirement which makes no sense, then there is no better solution than to follow orders, assuming you have understood them correctly (Sometimes it makes no sense because they don't know what they are doing, or you misunderstood).  You can set the thread pool to one and it will only handle one request at a time.

Comment: @PeterLawrey  Will one thread pool make one request at a time? Generally one  upload includes hundreds of IDs.During querying for one user on UPPER SITE, will another  upload arise  anither  query? And both will  run  at the  same time?

Comment: Depending on your server, a thread can only be handling one request at a time.  Unless you use a server based on asynchronous processing.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Can my server be like QUEUE, many INs at one time , only one OUT(query)?I have dozens of users,  7 minuters  is  a long  time.

Comment: You are using TCP in which has a queue of bytes both in and out.  So you will have a queue already, however if the server is taking 7 minutes to respond, the client is likely to time out.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative if you don't have access to the other website you can as a suggestion, create a worker thread that will query the other website for you. The workflow is as follows:

- When your client uploads a worker ID for querying details commit this to a database. Wake up worker thread. Set up this 'client' thread to poll your database for a result.
- Wake up a worker thread that will access your database for your worker ID details (there could of course be several as you may have several client threads committing to your db). This worker will query the other website, then commit the results to the database, if no work left, sleep thread.
- Client thread will see result and post result back to user and clean the result from your database.

Edit: I don't know the other websites architecture, this would probably work really well if the queries could be batched. If your website is a busy one and you can only query once per second you might need to look for an alternative solution..

Comment: One client wake up one worker thread, and many clients will wake up many worker thread.  "`This worker will query the other website`". this will make many querying thread.

Comment: My idea was to have one thread.. So you may have many clients that may try and wake this single thread. This thread is responsible for querying the other site for you and committing the query results to your local database. Your client threads will be polling your database for that result.. As I mentioned in my edit, the approach may be redundant if you cannot batch the query.. Your a bit limited for options really.